# I'm looking for a Python multiplayer game server project

Tags: python, multiplayer, mmo

I'm looking for a python multiplayer game server project. I'm just trying to learn more.

Answer (score 5):

Well I started on something simple [here](https://github.com/anacrolix/archive/tree/master/projects/pimu). It's written with [pygame](http://www.pygame.org/news.html) and Python's [socket module](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html). You could fork/learn from that.

Presently multiple players can login, move around, and do basic chat communication. There's also a goblin that chases the nearest player.